# Char.type vs Char in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
def findNonEqualTuples(value: String): List[(Char, Char)] = {
    val result = ListBuffer((Char,Char))
    for (current <- 0 until value.length / 2) {
      if (!value.charAt(current).equals(value.charAt(value.length - 1 - current))) {
        val tuple = (value.charAt(current), value.charAt(value.length - 1 - current))
        result += tuple
      }
    }
    return result.toList
  }
```

The line `result += tuple` says "**Type mismatch, expected: (Char.type, Char.type) actual: (Char, Char)**". I am quite new to scala. Could someone explain what is the difference between these two types and how I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in how you declare the `result` `ListBuffer`. Try:

```
val result = ListBuffer[(Char,Char)]()
```

Square-bracket notation is used for specifying parameter types. The compiler's interpretation of your code is that you want to create a new `ListBuffer` initialised to contain the tuple `(Char, Char)`, that is, a tuple containing the `Char` *type* (more accurately, as noted by @LuigiPlinge, it is the `Char` companion object - paired with itself) - hence the mismatch error.

**EDIT** - addressing the question in your comment:

this is a different type of braces issue :)
The key is to remember that even operators in Scala are in fact method calls,
so that `result += (...)` is actually sugar for:

```
result = result.+(...) // since "op=" is sugar for x = x op ...
```

ie. calling the `+=` method with the arguments contained within the parentheses. So, to pass a single argument consisting of a tuple, we need an extra set of parentheses:

```
result += ((value.charAt(current), value.charAt(value.length - 1 - current)))
```

The outer parentheses delimit the method's parameter list, while the inner parentheses encapsulate the tuple.

Comment: Great! Do you know why 'result += (value.charAt(current), value.charAt(value.length - 1 - current))' does not work, but storing it into val  and then adding to listBuffer works? I guess compiler misinterprets it

Comment: @xsx4u I have added to my answer to address your follow-up question (although you should consider asking such follow-ups as separate questions on SO).

Comment: How can you have a tuple containing a type... it's the `Char` companion object (the type of which is `Char.type`)

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Yes, you're right - it would be the companion object. Cheers.